# Angular 6 - Custom validator for taken emails always returns true

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder

I followed this Angular tutorial for a custom validator to check if an email has already been taken:
https://alligator.io/angular/async-validators/

My problem is that the validator always returns true, even when an email hasn't been taken yet (is not present in the database). Can anyone check what I'm doing wrong here?

The tutorial uses a JSON file with emails to check against. I use a real backend (spring framework) that's hooked up to a MySQL database. Everything works there as the http requests returns objects from the database.

This is my custom validator:

```
export class ValidateEmail {
  static createValidator(registerService: RegisterService) {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      return registerService.findByEmail(control.value).pipe(map(res => {
        return res ? { emailTaken: true } : null;

        // I also tried the below if/else statement, but it changes nothing
        // if(res){
        //   return ({emailTaken: true});
        // } else {
        //   return (null);
        // }

      }));
    }
  }
}
```

The RegisterService's method (I think something might be going wrong here?):

```
  findByEmail(email: string): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>('http://localhost:8080/user').pipe(
    map(users => users.filter(user => user.email === email)),
    catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }
```

RegisterComponent with the validators:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
    firstName: ['', Validators.required],
    lastName: ['', Validators.required],
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email], ValidateEmail.createValidator(this.registerService) ],
    username: ['', Validators.required],
    password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]]
  });
}
```

And the form template with the email input field:

```
<input formControlName="email" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" name="email"
       [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.email.errors }">
<div *ngIf="submitted && f.email.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
  <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.required">Email is required</div>
  <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.email">Email must be a valid email address</div>
  <!-- Below error always shows up, even when email has not been taken -->
  <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.emailTaken">An account with this email already exists</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return res ? { emailTaken: true } : null;
```

So the validator returns an error if `res` is truthy. What is `res`? It's

```
users.filter(user => user.email === email)
```

So it's an array, which could or could not be empty. An array, empty or not, is always truthy. So your validator always returns an error. You need to test if the array is empty or not. Not if it's truthy.

Comment: I changed the check in the validator to this: if(res.length !== 0) and it now works. Thank you!